# File-To-File using vectors - null result

Tags: java

Why have I got null in the text file test3.txt after read the elements of vectors correctly?

The problem is that the test1.txt consists of the string words, when I printed out the vector elements, it is OK, but when I print these elements vector to another file the other file is still null.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;
public class VectorFile {
    public static void main (String args []) throws IOException
    {
        Vector vc = new Vector();
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c://test1.txt"));
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("c://test3.txt");
        String s;
        while ((s = file.readLine()) != null) {
            vc.add(s);
        }

        file.close();

        System.out.println(vc.size());

        for(int i=0; i<vc.size(); i++){
            out.write( (String) vc.get(i));    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 3) Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: Could you post what is your actual output and your desired output? Don't use `Vector` use another implementation of `List` like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Also You should be using `List` instead of `Vector`.

Comment: @nachokk See [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214955/155831) for details, chase the links for more. ;)

Comment: the problem is that the test1.txt consists of the string words , when i printed out the vector elements, it is ok, but when i print these elements vector to another file the other file is still null

Comment: How the file is `null`. I don't understand

Comment: You miss out.flush(); below your for loop.

Comment: *"the problem is.."*  That sort of information should be [edited into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21065418/edit).  I have already done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute this:

```
for(int i=0; i<vc.size(); i++)
{
     out.write( (String) vc.get(i));    
}
```

with this:

```
for(int i=0; i<vc.size(); i++)
{
    out.write((String)vc.get(i)+ System.getProperty("line.separator"));    
}
out.flush();
```

Comment: More than likely this is correct (provided the OPs code actually is opening a file and reading any data). That said, `readline()` is going to strip the `\n` (or `\r\n`) off so it needs to be added back in the new file when writing. Also `out.close()` will flush.

Comment: a good edit, but if you put in a try with resources better ;) then it's `autocloseable` and don't need to use `close` or `flush` in this case

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below approach to write to the file instead of using a Vector.

```
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test1.txt"));
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\test3.txt"));
String line;
while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)
    writer.println(line);
writer.close();
```

But if you still need an intermediate data structure, I'd suggest a List instead of a Vector.

Comment: a Writer sends its output immediately to the underlying character or byte stream. Unless prompt output is required, it is advisable to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write() operations may be costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters. For example
 `PrintWriter out
   = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out")));`
will buffer the PrintWriter's output to the file. Without buffering, each invocation of a print() method would cause characters to be converted into bytes that would then be written immediately to the file, which can be very inefficient.